# TextView doesn't show Parse.com variables

Tags: android, parse-platform, null, textview

I have a TextView that suppose to view 2 variables that contains values from User Table on Parse.com, one is an int value and one is a String value. For some reason, when I load the activity (it's the main activity) it shows this: null - 0, when it supposed to show (string) - (int) (string and int are variables on the table. I can open another activity, but when I come back to the MainActivity, suddenly it shows the values that supposed to be on the TextView. I searched all over the code and I don't see a reason to this.

MainActivity.java query code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("_User");
query.getInBackground(userObjId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        score = user.getInt("score");
        king = user.getString("king");
    }
}
```

I also tried this method to get the values:

```
score = (int) user.get("score");
king = (String) user.get("king");
```

Please, what can I do to solve this? I have to upload the app to the play store until Sunday and I have no clue how to fix this bug...

Comment: You should set text in `TextView` just after getting the value in `getInBackground()`'s `done()` method.

Comment: as ved said, query.getInBackground() runs in background and the program flow doesn't wait till this process is finished. The done() is a call back, to let you know that, the getInBackground() has finished its work and now you can use the values. Also make sure to do null-check before assigning. We can better help you, if you can post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onCreate() {
  <..SOME CODE..>

  final TextView tvScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_score);
  final TextView tvKing = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_king);
  String userObjId = "<OBJECT_ID_HERE>";
  ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("_User");
  query.getInBackground(userObjId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
          score = user.getInt("score");
          king = user.getString("king");
          tvScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
          tvKing.setText(king);
      }
  }
}
```